# Flutter - How to check if dialog is shown when using go_router

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-go-router, flutter-dialog

I was using Navigator 1 then I migrated to [go_router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) to support deep links and web.
Sometimes when I send HTTP requests, I show a loading dialog using `showDialog()` until the response is processed, after processing I need to check if a dialog is shown or not, if shown I dismiss it using `Navigator.of(context).pop()`.

When I was using Navigator 1, I used to do that in this way:
`if (ModalRoute.of(context)?.isCurrent == false) Navigator.of(context).pop();`
But now after migrating to `go_router` this doesn't work as I found that `ModalRoute.of(context)` always equals to `null` whether there is a dialog shown or not.

I tried using `if (Navigator.of(context).canPop()) Navigator.of(context).pop();`, but this doesn't differentiate between dialogs and screens, if there is no dialog shown it pops the current screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by checking the `location` of `GoRouter`

```
if (GoRouter.of(context).location == '/dialog'){  Check here
    context.pop();
}
```

*Assuming your dialog route has path `/dialog`*

Comment: Thanks for your help,
But I actually don't show the dialog using the router, I use the `showDialog()` method which I believe uses the `Navigator` to push the dialog.
I updated my question.
So, I can't check for the location as I don't link the dialog to any route.

Answer (score 1):

I just use context.pop() on dialog dismiss.

Previously did it this way, but tends to throw.

Set a Global variable:

```
GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
```

In GoRouter specify:

```
navigatorKey: navKey
```

Pop dialog the 'old' way with:

```
Navigator.pop(navKey.currentContext!);
```

Correct me if it gives issues please.

Comment: I actually used this approach to handle this. I don't like the idea of setting a global variable and using it, but I think this is how it can be handled right now.

Comment: Doesn't router.pop() just do the job? @KhalidMuhammad

Comment: Nope, it actually pops one page from the stack.

Answer (score 1):

you can create the base class for dialog and define as below.
what ever dialog do you want to create extends the base class

**Note**: Don't forget to call supper class's methods if you are override the base class

```
abstract class BaseDialog {
      @protected
      final BuildContext context;
      bool _dialogShow = false;
    
      BaseDialog(this.context);
    
      Future<Object?> show() async {
        _dialogShow = true;
        return null;
      }
    
      void dismiss() {
        if (_dialogShow) {
          _dialogShow = false;
          context.pop();
        }
      }
    }
```